# LockScreen widget doesn't work properly

Tags: android, widget

I create a keyguard widget that has a button that upsate textview from SharedPreferences when clicking. it works properly on the home screen but on the lock screen (android 4.2.2) it(s button) works just when i add it to my lock screen widgets but when i turn screen off and return; it(s button) doesn't work !!

**Widget.java**

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider{
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for(int i=0;i<appWidgetIds.length;i++){
            long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, Widget_Resiver.class);
            intent.setAction("START_WIDGET_SERVICE");
            PendingIntent localPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 12, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            ((AlarmManager)context.getSystemService("alarm")).setRepeating(1, l, 120000L, localPendingIntent);
        }
    }

}
```

**Widget_Service.java**

```
public class Widget_Service extends Service{
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_BUTTON = "ACTION_WIDGET_BUTTON";
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),Widget.class);
        int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),R.layout.widget);

        SharedPreferences sP= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textView, String.valueOf(sP.getInt("updateTextView", 0)));

        Intent button = new Intent(this, Widget_Resiver.class);
        button.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_BUTTON);
        PendingIntent actionPendingIntentB2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, button, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, actionPendingIntentB2);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(allWidgetIds, views);
    }

}
```

**Widget_Resiver.java**

```
public class Widget_Resiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    public static String START_WIDGET_SERVICE="START_WIDGET_SERVICE";
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_BUTTON = "ACTION_WIDGET_BUTTON";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext());
         ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(),Widget.class);
         int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
         RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),R.layout.widget);

         SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
         SharedPreferences.Editor ed = settings.edit();


         if(intent.getAction().equals(START_WIDGET_SERVICE)){
             context.startService(new Intent(context, Widget_Service.class));

        }else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_BUTTON)) {
                ed.putInt("updateTextView", settings.getInt("updateTextView", 0)+1);
                ed.commit();
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textView,String.valueOf(settings.getInt("updateTextView", 0)));
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(allWidgetIds, remoteViews);
              } 
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".Widget" android:label="widget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget" />
</receiver>     
<service android:name=".Widget_Service"/>
<receiver android:name=".Widget_Resiver">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="ACTION_WIDGET_BUTTON"/>
         </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```